# Uploaded file, File type filter

Tags: symfony4

I created two entity for upload images, one for my articles (only used by me) and one for the profile picture of my users. I want to set a size limit and a file type filter, different for both entities.

Here is my code for the file

```
    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "206k",
     *     maxSizeMessage = "Le fichier de doit pas faire plus que ..",
     *     mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpg"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Seul les formats ..."
     * )
     */
    private $file;

    public function getFile() {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file): void {
        $this->file = $file;
    }
```

I can still upload any kind of files, and the only size limit I have is from my php.ini

Answer (score 0):

The file upload size and mime type checks work for me using Symfony 4.3.1 with Doctrine and MySQL.  Two changes are to specify the `@ORM\Column` type and change `image/jpg` to `image/jpeg`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "206k",
 *     maxSizeMessage = "Le fichier de doit pas faire plus que ..",
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpeg"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Seul les formats ..."
 * )
 */
private $file;
```

Also have you tried `php bin/console cache:clear`
and tried `php bin/console make:migration` to check if the Entities and database are in sync?

Comment: Yes, I tried, I don't understand why it doesn't work, I certainly did something wrong. After many searches, I read that you can apply constraints in form, what I did and it works!